# objects of same class have different methods signature

Tags: scala, anonymous-class

look at the following snippet:

```
class C
val c1 = new C { def m1 = "c1 has m1" }
val c2 = new C { def m2 = "c2 has m2" }

c1.m1
c2.m2
//c2.m1
//c1.m2
```

run it in the REPL, then you know what I mean.

My limited java knowledge tells me that in java, objects of same class will have the same methods signagure, and as far as OO concerned, there is no much difference between java and scala under the hood. (correct me, if I'm wrong), so I'm very surprised to see the snippet is sound scala code.

so why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're extending `C` with traits, so `c1` and `c2` are anonymous classes :

```
scala> c1.getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_ <: C] = class $anon$1

scala> c2.getClass
res1: java.lang.Class[_ <: C] = class $anon$2
```

Looking at the java code, you'll see (`O` being a surrounding object to get it to compile) :

```
public final class O$$anon$1 extends O$C {
  public java.lang.String m1();
  public O$$anon$1();
}

public final class O$$anon$2 extends O$C {
  public java.lang.String m2();
  public O$$anon$2();
}
```

Comment: thanks Marth, by the way, in the scala repl, I use :type c1 and :type c2, the result don't give me any indication that trait is involved here.

Comment: Anonymous classes don't form part of the (externally-visible) type.

Answer (score 1):

The Java equivalent is

```
C c1 = new C { 
    public String m1() { ... }
}

C c2 = new C { 
    public String m2() { ... }
}
```

Now, you can't call `c1.m1()` directly, but you can do it using reflection:

```
c1.getClass().getMethod("m1").invoke(c1)
```

Scala just allows you to do it with a simpler syntax.